# Flutter Stateless Class and Statefull class Stuck to use

Tags: api, flutter, updates

I'm new on Flutter I'm stuck to use stateless class and stateful class.....
in my this program I want to pass a value to my Stateful class look downside in that please check "PHOTOLIST" class in that class items show error even same code I used in stateless class ALL OKAY in that case....! plz solve my this issue..." pls Focus on PHOTOLIST"...u will see my problem in that part that items are showing errors! Thank You U gUYS are awesome when someone gets into trouble

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:photogranth2020/data/CampaignFolderSummery.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'CampaignSinglePhotos.dart';
import 'data/CampaignPhotosdata.dart';
 class CampaignPhotos extends StatefulWidget {
 int FolderId;
String BuisnessName;
CampaignPhotos({@required this.BuisnessName,this.FolderId});

@override
_CampaignPhotosState createState() => _CampaignPhotosState();
 }

class _CampaignPhotosState extends State<CampaignPhotos> {
String AccessToken;
int CustomerId;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

Future<PhotoList> Photolist() async {
sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Map data = {
  "AccessToken": sharedPreferences.getString("AccessToken"),
  "CustomerId":  sharedPreferences.getInt("CustomerId"),
  "FolderId": widget.FolderId
};
print(data);

final http.Response response = await http.post(
  "http://api.pgapp.in/v1/photoslist",
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(data),
);
debugPrint(response.body);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the server did return a 201 CREATED response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  return PhotoList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
} else {
  // If the server did not return a 201 CREATED response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Failed to load data');
}
}

Future<FolderSummery> FolderSummary() async {
sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Map data =
{
  "AccessToken": sharedPreferences.getString("AccessToken"),
  "CustomerId":  sharedPreferences.getInt("CustomerId"),
  "FolderId": widget.FolderId
};

print(data);

final http.Response response = await http.post(
  "http://api.pgapp.in/v1/photographer/campaign/folder/summary",
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(data),
 );
 debugPrint(response.body);
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the server did return a 201 CREATED response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  return FolderSummery.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
 } else {
  // If the server did not return a 201 CREATED response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Failed to load data');
 }
 }


Future<PhotoList> _futurePhotoList;
Future<FolderSummery> _futureSummary;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_futurePhotoList = Photolist();
_futureSummary = FolderSummary();

}


  ////////@@@@@@@   INISTATE call when Selection errror############

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xfff8f8f8),
      leading: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 1,top: 5,bottom: 5),
        child: Container(
            height: 8,
            width: 35,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_left,color: Color(0xfff58634,),size: 40,),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
      title: Center(
          child: Text("Dhara Weds Bharat",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,),)
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20,top: 5,bottom: 5),
          child: Container(
              height: 8,
              width: 35,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list,color: Color(0xfff58634),size: 40,),
              )
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    body:
    (_futurePhotoList == null)
        ? Text("No data found. Please try again later.")
        : FutureBuilder<PhotoList>(
      future: _futurePhotoList,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return PhotoListing(
            itemss: snapshot.data.photoList,
          );
        }
        else {
          return Center(child:
          CircularProgressIndicator()
          );
        }
      },
    )
 );
 }
 }

 class PhotoListing extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _PhotoListingState createState() => _PhotoListingState();
 } 

class _PhotoListingState extends State<PhotoListing> {

 final List<PhotoListElement> itemss;

  PhotoListing({Key key, this.itemss});

num countValue = 2 ;
bool _selectionMode = false;
bool selected = false;
List<int> _selectedIndexList = List();

changeMode(){

if(countValue == 2){
  countValue = 1 ;
}
else{
  countValue = 2 ;
}
}
void _changeSelection({bool enable, int index}) {
_selectionMode = enable;
_selectedIndexList.add(index);
if (index == -1) {
  _selectedIndexList.clear();
}
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      top: 2,
      left: 1,
      right: 3,
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        color: Color(0xfff8f8f8),
        child: FutureBuilder<FolderSummery>(
          // ignore: missing_return
          builder: (context , snapshot){
            int Like;
            int Comment;
            Like = snapshot.data.likeCount;
            Comment = snapshot.data.commentCount;
            if (snapshot.hasData){
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    child:
                    Icon(Icons.play_arrow,size: 35,color: Color(0xfff58634),),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 135,top: 5,bottom: 5),
                    child:  Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.thumb_up,color: Color(0xfff58634)),
                          Text("$Like",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,),),
                        ]
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 5,bottom: 5),
                    child:  Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.chat_bubble,color: Color(0xfff58634)),
                          Text("$Comment",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,),),
                        ]
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 5,bottom: 5),
                    child:  Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.share,color: Color(0xfff58634)),
                          Text("33",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,),),
                        ]
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 5,bottom: 5),
                    child:  Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.photo_album,color: Color(0xfff58634),),
                          Text("10",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45,),),
                        ]
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 55),
      child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        crossAxisCount: countValue,
        primary: false,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4,
        mainAxisSpacing: 4,
        itemCount: itemss.length,
        itemBuilder: (context , int index){
          if (_selectionMode) {
            return GridTile(
              header: GridTileBar(
                trailing: Icon(
                  _selectedIndexList.contains(index) ? Icons
                      .check_circle_outline : Icons
                      .radio_button_unchecked,
                  color: _selectedIndexList.contains(index) ? Colors
                      .green : Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  child: Image.network(itemss[index].photoMainImagePath,
                    height: 50,
                    width: 100,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,),

                ),
                onLongPress: () {
                  _changeSelection(enable: false, index: -1);
                },
                onTap: () {
                  if (_selectedIndexList.contains(index)) {
                    _selectedIndexList.remove(index);
                  } else {
                    _selectedIndexList.add(index);
                  }

                },
              ),

            );
          }
          else
          {
            return GridTile(
              child: InkResponse(
                child: Image.network(itemss[index].photoMainImagePath,
                  height: 50,
                  width: 100,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                onLongPress: () {
                  _changeSelection(enable: true, index: index);
                },
                onTap:(){
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                      CampaignSinglePhotos( Backgroundimg: itemss[index].photoMainImagePath,
                      )));
                },
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 1.2 : 1.8),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 1,
      width: 400,
      height: 70,
      child: ClipRect(
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),

          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 15,
      left: 20,
      child: Image.asset("assets/images/camlogo.jpg",height: 45,width: 45,),
    ),
    Positioned(
        bottom: 23,
        left: 30,
        right: 30,
        child: Center(child: Text("Sultania Photography",style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,color: Colors.black
        ),))
    ),
    Positioned(
        right: 13,
        bottom: 15,
        child: Center(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/user.jpg"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              maxRadius: 22,
            )
        )
    ),
    Positioned(
        right: 13,
        bottom: 80,
        child: Center(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => changeMode(),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                child: Icon(Icons.crop_free,color: Colors.red,),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                maxRadius: 22,
              ),
            )
        )
    ),
  ],
 );
 }
  }
```

Comment: You need to show the error your receiving. Appreciate english is a second language but its hard to know what the problem is.

Comment: And what does the error message say?

Comment: Iteam count Undefined